# Missing Assembly - using OxyPlot in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-assembly, oxyplot

I'm working with OxyPlot in WPF. Trying to name my plotview I get compiler-error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'Wpf' does not exist in the namespace 'NameOfProject' (are
>   you missing an assembly reference?)

my XAML-code very simple:

```
<Window x:Class="NameOfProject"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Wpf;assembly=OxyPlot.Wpf"
        Title="Plot_MV" Height="auto" Width="auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="10,10,0,10"
            Content="ExportToPDF"
            Height="30"
            Width="80"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Button_Click">            
        </Button>

        <oxy:PlotView 
            x:Name="plotName"
            Model="{Binding plotModel}" 
            Grid.Row="1">            
        </oxy:PlotView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm using XS Express 2012 and OxyPlot Version 2015.1.1046.0
Anyone an idea to fix it?

Comment: I use Oxyplut to, but my xmlns is this one, try this: `xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"`

Comment: I tried - same error

Comment: Cannot be the same error if you does not use .Wpf in any other xmlns. Maybe your problem is on the references of your project, did you correctly added the oxyplot library to your project?

Comment: Your `x:Class` has to be qualified (with namespace).

Comment: Yes it's the same error - Yes libraries are correctly added

Comment: Which oxyplot libraries do you have added?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your class: `MyWindow`:

```
namespace MyProject {
    public class MyWindow : Window 
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Then in `XAML` your class need to be qualified (with namespace)

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MyWindow" ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My class is qualified with namespace
`<Window x:Class=Projectname.Folder.Window"`